# Is it known whether this space is a suspension space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For each prime $p\geq 3$ let $\alpha_p:S^{2p}\to S^3$ denote a representative of $\pi_{2p}S^3$ of order $p$. Berstein and Hilton showed that for each $p$ the homotopy cofiber $C_{\alpha_p}$ of $\alpha_p$ is a co-H-space which does not have the homotopy type of a suspension space.

The maps $\alpha_p$ give rise to a map $\alpha:\bigvee_{p\geq 3} S^{2p}\to S^3$ whose cofiber $C_\alpha$ is a co-H-space. Is it known whether $C_\alpha$ has the homotopy type of a suspension space?

Comment: Have you tried extending the proof of Lemma 3.6 in Berstein and Hilton to show that if $C_\alpha$ is a suspension then each of the $\alpha_p$ must be suspensions?

Comment: I gave that a shot, but at some point Berstein and Hilton require a particular map to be injective on homotopy groups; I couldn't convince myself that the analogs of that map that arise in the construction of $C_\alpha$ enjoy this property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't the localization of a 2-connected suspension also a suspension?  Then this cannot be a suspension.  (Brayton Gray pointed this out to me.)

Comment: This is true, since (i) localization commutes with homotopy pushouts, and (ii) a 2-connected suspension is a suspension of a 1-connected space, by the argument in Lemma 3.6 of Berstein and Hilton

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good answer to me. Is the rhetorical question the problem?